# Convert JSON property to int php

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, server

i have this code in javascript:

```
var oRows= [];
 for(var i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i ++) {
 var oItem = {name: "example", id: i};
 oRows.push(oItem);
}
 $.ajax({
   url: '/savejson.php',
   method: 'post',
   data: { 'oRows': oRows }
 }).done(function (data) {
     console.log(data);
 });
```

and code in the php:

```
<?php
        $fp = fopen('/data/DecisionTableRows.json', 'w');
        fwrite($fp, json_encode($_POST['oRows']));
        fclose($fp);
?>
```

but in the JSON file `/data/DecisionTableRows.json` i still get the property Id as string, how i can write it as int?

Comment: You need to perform an explicit type case on the server side, since http request values are typeless. Alternatively you can send the final JSON format from client to server.

Comment: Do you really need it as an integer, and not a string, and couldn't you just type cast it wherever you need it instead.

Comment: Do a `JSON.stringify` before sending the post data to the server and write it without a `json encode`. `$_POST` variables will always be strings.

Comment: I need it as a int not string. @apokryfos coulde explain please?

Comment: I think he's saying that if you do `data: { 'oRows': JSON.stringify(oRows) }` and send it as a string, and then don't encode on the serverside, you'll preserve the integers.

Comment: @adeneo so how i can write it to the json file?

Comment: Jeez `fwrite($fp, $_POST['oRows']);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that $_POST variables are always strings.

To avoid the headache of manually doing an `is_numeric` and casting on each one of them in PHP you can do this:

```
var oRows= [];
 for(var i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i ++) {
 var oItem = {name: "example", id: i};
 oRows.push(oItem);
}
 $.ajax({
   url: '/savejson.php',
   method: 'post',
   data: { 'oRows': JSON.stringify(oRows) }
 }).done(function (data) {
     console.log(data);
 });
```

and in PHP

```
<?php
        $fp = fopen('/data/DecisionTableRows.json', 'w');
        fwrite($fp, $_POST['oRows']);
        fclose($fp);
?>
```

This way you shift the responsibility of encoding to JSON over to JavaScript which does have the original data to work with.